# Can cloud function detect online user from mobile app and execute function for mobile app?

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Form Mobile app for submitting a string data (string userPresent = "online") to Firebase Database whenever user is online/open the app.

The string data will be deleted from the database after user click exit or close the app.

The problem is when user close the internet before closing the app, the string data won't be deleted from the database after they leave.

So is there any solution for this or can Firebase cloud function connect with my app, detect online user, and execute functions when the user lost their connection/go offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't indicate if you use the Realtime Database or Firestore (they are two different DB services).

In both cases you could use the [presence system](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html), which is based on the Realtime Database, but which can also be used to add presence to a Cloud Firestore app, by actually using Cloud Functions to keep Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore in sync, see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence).

Comment: Okay sir this sounds like a perfect solution for my problem. I will test it out!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new data at Firebase Database called `LastOnlineDateTime` for each user and update this value in every 1/5/10 minutes depending on how much accurate data you need.

And in the other hand, if any other user is checking this user status you can find the user status based on property `LastOnlineDateTime`. If date time is before your interval then you can show this user as online. Or else you can show when was this user online.

In this solution you don't have to worry about your App exit event or internet connection lose.

Comment: Sir, but in my case i must clear the data (userPresent) out from my database because otherwise other users can't come online because i limit 10 users online only, so i must clear the data from database, so the app can count the number user again, but i can't find the solution yet.

Comment: @ProjectG okay, in that case you can write a `cloud function` with a time interval (5 minutes) and it should check all users `LastOnlineDateTime` property and if it's earlier than 10 minutes, then this function should set the data `userPreset` of the specific user.